# Google Adsense Valuable inventory: no content

Tags: javascript, ads, adsense

I have applied for Google Adsense a couple of times now and every time I get this Valuable inventory: no content. I added more content to the pages and everything but I am still getting this. I see many other pages with less content than mine that have ads. Can you guys take a look and let me know what I can do?

https://webtoolbox42.com

Answer (score 2):

You have a 6% code to text ratio.
You should add more content (text and images) to your homepage. It's to much white space.
Adsense can't know what your site is about with this little information.

Try starting a blog, tell people what the tool is about or give examples.
Remember, do it on the Homepage as it has little text.